# TestCafe Role does not return to specified fixture page

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to use Roles for Testcafe. When I use a Role it does not bring me back to the specified fixture page. The docs say this is how it is supposed to work, but I cannot seem to get it working.

Goals:

1. Use Role to login
2. Return to page.libraryScreen once the Role is used.

Here is my code:

```
fixture`Library /all`.page(page.libraryScreen).beforeEach(async t => {
  await t.useRole(page.adminUser);
});

test('Search Bar', async t => {
  const searchIcon = Selector('div').withAttribute('class', 'CampaignsPage-fab1');
  const microAppNameInput = Selector('input').withAttribute('placeholder', 'Search');
  const microAppTitle = Selector('div').withAttribute('class', 'SetCard-title ').innerText;
  const searchIconElement = searchIcon.with({ visibilityCheck: true })();

  await t
    .click(searchIconElement)
    .typeText(microAppNameInput, testMicroAppTitle)
    .expect(microAppTitle)
    .eql(testMicroAppTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems I needed to use { preserveUrl: true } in Role. For example:

```
this.adminUser = Role(
  this.loginScreen,
  async t => {
    const emailInput = Selector('input').withAttribute('placeholder', 'Email');
    const passwordInput = Selector('input').withAttribute('placeholder', 'Password');

    await t
      .typeText(emailInput, this.email)
      .typeText(passwordInput, this.password)
      .click(this.submit);
  },
  { preserveUrl: true }
);
```